# 80's young adult series about a quest to unlock gates

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm trying to remember a series (trilogy I think) that I read back in the 80's...

All I can really remember is that there was a young main character (maybe a prince?) that had to go on a quest - the quest either involved unlocking gates to continue travelling, or consisted of actually unlocking the gates.

It was a fantasy series, and I seem to remember he had to wear a mask (maybe a golden mask?). It's all really fuzzy.  The series was probably released in the 80's because I remember picking the first one up at our library on the "new releases" shelf.

Comment: Sounds kind of like the Neverending Story, but I don't have a copy with me.  Can anyone else corroborate?

Comment: Neither do I, but I don't remember Bastian wearing a gold mask...

Comment: Shot in the dark: The gates and the publication time imply Cherryh's Morgaine Cycle (3, later 4 books), however the gates had to be locked rather than unlocked, and it wouldn't really make sense that you would not remember Morgaine herself, even though it's written from Vanye's POV.

Answer (score 3):

This is odd, second time I've seen a question for this series today.  *[The Seven Citadels](https://www.goodreads.com/series/62064-seven-citadels)* by Geraldine Harris.

1. *[Prince of the Godborn](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/675444.Prince_of_the_Godborn)*
2. *[The Children of the Wind](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/675418.The_Children_of_the_Wind)*
3. *[The Dead Kingdom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/675423.The_Dead_Kingdom)*
4. *[The Seventh Gate](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/675425.The_Seventh_Gate)*

Summary for the first book:

> Foreign armies and royal feuds threaten the Empire of Galkis. Darkness and destruction lie ahead unless the Galkians rescue their savior, who, according to ancient myths, is trapped somewhere behind seven locked gates. Prince Kerish-lo-Taan, the Emperor's favorite son, makes a big decision: to leave the safety of Galkis and take his half-brother Forollkin on a dangerous quest for the legendary savior. First, Kerish and Forollkin must find the Seven Sorcerers who guard the keys to the gates. Can Kerish's Godborn powers help him avoid peril, and capture the golden keys?

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember an Andre Norton which I think had the protagonist led through a series of gates by a group of brown skinned superior beings, maybe *[Star Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Gate_(novel))*.

> Long ago people came from beyond the sky and landed on Gorth. There they raised the humanoid natives out of the wild state and led them to develop a civilization analogous to that of Medieval Europe. Then they went away, leaving behind a few of their number, memories, and a small population of cross-breeds. Kincar s’Rud is one of those cross-breeds. Part native and part Star Lord, he has assumed that he will inherit the throne of a small fief when his grandfather dies. Instead, his grandfather bestows upon him the livery of a Star Lord and warns him to leave Styr Holding immediately, because his uncle intends to kill him in order to take the throne for himself.
>
> Riding his larng Cim, the four-eyed analogue of a horse, and accompanied by his pterodactyl-like hunting mord, Vorken, he leaves the only world he has known, following a map that his grandfather gave him. Falling in with a party of cross-breeds and a Star Lord, he helps them fight off outlaws and follows them through a pair of luminous webs to another Gorth. As they pass through the Star Gate Kincar is burned by an amulet, a Tie, that he wears. Joined by others, the group takes refuge in an abandoned keep that they find on their new world. Kincar meets a healer, Lady Asgar, who treats his burn while Lord Dillan tells him about many worlds and of travel between them. They have come to a Gorth that they had not intended to occupy, so they will have to build another Star Gate.
>
> While out hunting, Kincar captures a small man who was trying to steal his kill. Back at the keep the man reacts to the Star Lords’ presence with fear, telling the refugees that the Star Lords he knows, the Dark Ones, are cruel people who have enslaved the native Gorthians. One of the Dark Ones is Rud, a doppelgänger of Kincar’s father.
>
> Kincar volunteers to reconnoiter the lands occupied by the Dark Ones and their slaves. Before he can even reach the city where he would spy out what the refugees need to know, he is captured and taken to an open field to be eaten alive by mords. The Tie burns the thug who tries to take it and the mords finish him off while Vorken, who has become leader of the flock, protects Kincar.
>
> Astounded by Kincar’s survival, the evil Lords Rud and Dillan take him and Vorken to the place where their starships stand grounded. Desperate, putting his faith in the Tie, Kincar escapes and goes back to the mountains to meet up again with the refugees and the bastard son of this Gorth’s Rud.
>
> In the aircar that Kincar used in his escape, the Star Lords go to the starships on a day when all of the Dark Lords will be in them. They set the automatic controls and send the ships back into space, thereby ending the cruel dictatorship of the Dark Ones. The Star Lords then use materials that they took from the ships to build another Star Gate and they, Kincar and the other refugees pass through it into yet another alternate Gorth.

Comment: Looks like you're referring to [this novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Gate_(novel)). You might want to [edit] your answer to add more details, e.g. by quoting from that Wikipedia page. See also [How to write a good story-ID answer?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394)